# local host site, outputting random text

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I started to do some updates to a site this morning, and when I went to run it, I am getting random text instead of the site.

The site is setup on a local url, mysite.local, with an entry in hosts to map it to my PC.

I have tried a "clean and rebuild" in VS, IIS Reset, Recycling the app pool, re booting the PC, and even creating a new entry in IIS, but nothing solves it.

It only appears to be happening on aspx pages, as I can load .htm pages without error.

I need to get some updates done today, so any help would be fantastic!

Here is the text it's outputting

```
���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6�����h���ly���,�&?�O�t�-���7������bU���'/���lR��_�|�fm�&_��W���fmQ-��Ǐ� 0z�^��jv����j�n�g���~��O��,[f��Wyq1o-�z���QS� �����iUV��I�M���ԃ�z�>�EV_���Z=J���������T���������f�����Z���gir�k�ܷ ��ZPWu������e�   �tU� \g�a��_��y��� �J�����ߵ۳|Z��B��e��P�y��W�/�/��:l��uE})�'U�V�G����]�ݻU��e��F�v{^/gy]�{�#����.���u��su�S��]���U1�?��'賏��E�d�� B����w�^�5�;=������������������vwv~���ٮ��YS���������|�(}\|S�^a�{�c�� �Lϳi��G�u�����9!��Q�y��/�����u�l�_��2�Gi����.���&G�Ӽ���J8������2]/1#%�F�n��wi5�ɂ���u��H�yN��ӵ|{�pB�*��u���yӎӗe�59�}Y�Wܬi�_Ӷ������")���*�M�u+]��6��^ξ��K��-ۄ������[u�j�ܢ�?���eA��v����hp�t1�6��|x����ٚѯ�[���.i�����bU���f]���6����M���<|x�40b�gŲh��,ǹ���A���ClY�y��_2�����t���������$h�[��홈�zD�pM���ziI��f��r*��=|x��!��b�$\�����ҧ�c�(����w<[�y��JE�E���u^_o��v:A���l���M��X�����M�u���x���|2~�7�S�{�613C�   L �h�C��Š�䧍��r�i4��)�����   �����?�����;����-%q1�����buHF,I����:��j ��*g����#MW�m�̷�ݶ+��;yO��N60�Ì���C�:!����!�.�+����nF����j�.sR��&�e4�B�����踾h���F�>�{�-��W�.���ϲ�rk~�.��F���6�ʭ1��pUn�y�Q��yK�u}�����ug�V7:2���z��qanD��p`"�t�oΝ�Eg��f�<��8��>�P=�j
```

The latest thing I have tried is to bring down the code from svn into a brand new folder, create a new entry in IIS and point at this. I am still getting the same issue after this!!

Also, other sites running locally are not getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, problem solved!

I turned out to be an issue with my session tables.
I followed the steps outlined in this post, and it solved my problem:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1313929.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have enabled gzip.

In your `Application_Error` make sure you remove the custom response filter:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    app.Response.Filter = null;
}
```

Rick Strahl described the problem in more details in his [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats).

Comment: I tried that, but I get the following error
Response filter is not valid.

Comment: Also, I did a search for gzip in my project, and got no results (I was pretty sure it wasn't being used)

Comment: OK, moring blindness, I'd added that code in the wrong part of global. I now get the error Invalid object name 'MyDatabase.dbo.ASPStateTempApplications'. So, I am currently trying the steps outlined in http://forums.asp.net/t/1313929.aspx/1

Comment: @mp3duck, now at least you no longer get garbage and you get the correct error message which was your original question. As far as your actual error is concerned, this no longer relates to this question. I would recommend you opening a new question in which you provide more details about your application and the error message you are getting.